# Dynamic table name based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some tables which have dates in it.

How can I query on them based on the dates. There are multiple tables with prefix_date format.

I mean if the name of the table is foo and today's date being 2016 06 09. The table I need to access will be `foo_2016_06_09`.

I need to run this query daily on the day before date. Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y_%m_%d')`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) will return as `2016_06_09`, you can concatenate the remain table name part and use as [dynamic query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/):

```
SET @table_name:='foo_';
SET @date_part:=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y_%m_%d');

SET @sql:=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table_name, @date_part);
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

For the previous day, use [`DATE_SUB`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

```
SET @date_part:=DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y_%m_%d');
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful? If it is not working please add some comment, then we can add/update the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was a bit helpful