# Make a select from a table with year and month as a name using mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm using mariadb and I have to make a select to a table. Table names are created every month for each year. So you can find on the DDBB table_202301, table_202302, ... and go on.

So depending the day I want to get the data I have to query one table or another. So le'ts suppose I have to get data from yesterday. I'm using:

```
SELECT CONCAT('table', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%m'));
```

And I get the table name: `table202301`

So that works fine! But when I want to get all rows from this table using:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.CONCAT('table', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%m'));
```

I get sintax error (1064). I've been also trying to CONCAT dbname and use commas for delimiting database but I get same error message. Can you help me with it?

Comment: `dbname.CONCAT(...)` isn't a valid CONCAT() invocation (unless there is a schema dbname having a function named concat.)

Comment: You need dynamic SQL here. Or have a SELECT that creates a script, e.g. something similar to `SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tablename, ';') FROM tables`.

Comment: This looks like pretty bad database design.  You should instead have _one_ table with a date column.  Even if you have so much data that a single day's worth is extremely large, you can still do horizontal partitioning.

Comment: also trying: `SELECT * FROM ``dbname``.CONCAT('table', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), '%m'));` (simple quote on dbname) returns same error.

Comment: CONCAT returns a string, right?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer on this question. So dynamic SQL must be used.

[Dynamic table name based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717436/dynamic-table-name-based-on-date)